# gsettings not working from within Bash function

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm pretty new to bash and only 6 months into Ubuntu so please bear with me.

I'm creating a post installation script https://github.com/jjdemitriUk/relutionDev written in bash. The reason I have everything separated into functions is because I have more than one machine that uses Ubuntu and this is a script that allows me to modularize what I want to install on a particular unit like my laptop gets a dev pack home comp gets media and common post install.

I've got to the setting function and I understand there are two ways of changing the settings.

1. Back up your original preinstall & copy over post install... not working on this yet
2. Run a simple command from the terminal such as `gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session show-real-name-on-panel true`

In the terminal I type

```
 gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session show-real-name-on-panel true
```

And the real name appears in the panel :)

Put it in a function

```
function homeSettings(){
   echo "Changing Settings";
   gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session show-real-name-on-panel true;
   echo "Setting Changed";
}
```

and when run from terminal

```
./relutionDev homeSettings
```

I get terminal output of the `echo`es so I know its being called but no change of settings. I've been banging my head against a wall to no avail. I've looked at other questions with close relation to mine regarding changing wallpaper and cron jobs but mine isn't a wallpaper or a cron job. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: @OP The link is dead. Did you move the script? I was going to try it out on my docker envs. Ive been using devcontainers for development, and this sounds like it would save me some time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running your installation script with `sudo` but `gsettings` are a per user configuration system. that's why you're no seeing any change.

Try without `sudo` (as a normal user) and it should work.